# RSpec accessing application_controller methods such as 'current_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to stub out a method on my current_user (using a modified restful_authentication auth solution) with rspec.  I'm completely unsure of how I can access this method in my controller specs.  current_user by itself doesn't work.  Do I need to get the controller itself first?  How do I do this?

Using `rails 2.3.5`, `rspec 1.3.0` and `rspec-rails 1.3.2`

```
# my_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyController do

  let(:foos){ # some array of foos }

  it "fetches foos of current user" do
    current_user.should_receive(:foos).and_return(foos)
    get :show
  end
end
```

Produces

```
NoMethodError in 'ChallengesController fetches foos of current user'
undefined method `current_user' for #<Spec::Rails::Example::ControllerExampleGroup::Subclass_1::Subclass_1::Subclass_2::Subclass_2:0x7194b2f4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rspec-rails gives you a `controller` method for use in controller examples. So:

`controller.stub!(:current_user).with(:foos).and_return(foos)`

ought to work.

Comment: awesome, i'll test this out, btw, what's the difference between `stub` and `stub!`

Comment: None - `stub` is an alias for `stub!`, so they are interchangeable

Answer (score 1):

how can it know where to find `current_user`? this should solve it:

```
subject.current_user.should_receive(:foos).and_return(foos)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with restful_authentication, just Authlogic and Devise, but it's probably similar in that `current_user` is a controller method and not an object, which is why calling `should_receive` on it isn't working as expected (you're setting an expectation on the object that `current_user` *returns*, but the method isn't accessible inside the scope of your expectation).

Try this:

`stub!(:current_user).and_return(foos)`

Comment: i couldn't get it t owork with just stub() I needed controller.stub as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I read this and tweaked mine a bit.  If you simply want to pass in a user object into your Rspec test, you can use this:

1. First, create a user object within the rspec test.  For example:
   (use whatever attributes you need or are required to create the user object.)

   user = User.create(name: "ted")

   (Note: you can also use a factory from FactoryGirl.)
2. Now, with that user object which is saved into the variable "user", do this within that same Rspec test:

   controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(user)

that should work...